# How to evaluate condition before route change in Angular?

Tags: angular

I use Firebase in Angular, and I use a function that returns the currently signed in user, either `firebase.User` or `null`, depending on the authorization state of the user.

If the user is logged in and opens the webpage, they arrive first on the landing-page and will eventually redirected to their account page around 200ms later.

I am trying to remove the flicker of the landing-page. Does Angular allow me to evaluate a condition before a route change? Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a route guard to inspect whether a user is authenticated before resolving to the route target. This will prevent the redirect flicker you mentioned.

https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access